# Weird common lisp error (sbcl)

Tags: lisp

I am having a really wierd lisp error. I am using sbcl and have written the following code. I am just hoping someone could explain.

```
(setq x '((1 (x y) (1 2)) (3 (x z) (2 3)) (3 (x y) (1 2)) (4 (x y) (1 2))))

(caddadr x)
```

gives the following error message

; Evaluation aborted on #.

however writing it in the for gives me what I was expecting which is

```
(car (cddadr x))
(2 3)
```

just wondering why this is to be honest.

Comment: SBCL has quite verbose output so I'm puzzled you only got one line.. If I enter your lines in my REPL it's not happy with either of the lines since `setq` is not good for global variable (use either `defparameter` or `defvar`) and of course the essence of the next 20 lines of errors has **undefined function** mentioned numerous times.

Comment: I was only using the setq as a quick way to enter long inputs without having to write them out again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function as `caddadr`, that's why.

```
* (fboundp 'caddadr)

NIL
* (fboundp 'cddadr)

T
```

You have just `CAR, CDR, CAAR, CADR, CDAR, CDDR, CAAAR, CAADR, CADAR, CADDR, CDAAR, CDADR, CDDAR, CDDDR, CAAAAR, CAAADR, CAADAR, CAADDR, CADAAR, CADADR, CADDAR, CADDDR, CDAAAR, CDAADR, CDADAR, CDADDR, CDDAAR, CDDADR, CDDDAR and CDDDDR`. See: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm

Comment: I dont understand how this is the case. I thought you could combine car and cdr as much as you wanted?

Comment: @tony: You can combine `car` and `cdr` as much as you want (as in `(car (cdr (car foo)))`), but the number of these convenience shorthands can only be finite, since they are named by symbols that must exist.  You might define your own convenience function that takes the “path” as a parameter (as in `(cxr foo :a :d :a)`, but I believe that an even more general chaining operator (I think Clojure has `->`) makes that superfluous (as in `(-> foo #'car #'cdr #'car)`.